# Firebase onMessageReceived() not called from http request

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

After discovering that sending notifiactions from the Firebase console, if the app is in background the onMessageReceived() method is not called.

I therefore followed peoples advice to use a HTTP POST Request.
I have been using postman to make a post request

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

with 2 headers:

Content-Type: application/json

Authorization: key=ALsa.......6ryLiI

and body

```
 {
 "to" : "fzgh-aHiOd8:APA91bFcKuwuVq_2gbLydHkAZf9XLUzm9vPalh7EUQT3Kyj8mcW9raAs9QvxbHaGJ4-U4RnUJwJ3UaEarbMXiQ8rHnsx9UuYBDrOI9tJYB78_Z3VVR1l7H_6PGpCkdgINx8a4vvMXD9q",
"notification" : {
    "body" : "Sales!",
    "title" : "ID Phone",
    "icon" : "myicon"
},
"data" : {
    "data" : "sales",

}
```

}

Now, the notification does come into my app (which is good), but its still not the custom notifcation that I wanted. ie onMessageReceived() is still not being called.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: check whether data is recieved or not. as your registrant id or server api key might not be correct

Comment: Data is being received. Still not working though. Thanks

Comment: When you send a notification message and your app is in the background, a notification will be displayed in the notification tray. Your app's `onMessageReceived` will not be invoked. This is expected behavior. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define a data payload to get a message in the onmessagereceived(). notification tag is for notifications only.

See this from GCM [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages):

> **Data messages**
>
> Set data with your custom key/value pairs to send a data payload to
>   the client app. Data messages can have a maximum 4KB payload.
>
> For example, here is a JSON-formatted message in the same IM
>   application as above, where the information is encapsulated in data
>   and the client app is expected to interpret the content:
>
> ```
>  {
>    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
>    "data" : {
>      "Nick" : "Mario",
>      "body" : "great match!",
>      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
>    },
>  }
> ```

**EDIT**

Replace these

```
Content-Type - application/json
Authorization - key=ALsa.......6ryLiI
```

with

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=ALsa.......6ryLiI
```

Comment: I found another mistake and edited my answer.

Comment: thanks, helped me a lot. marked as accepted